# When building app for visionOS only, code inside os(iOS) directive is used

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, directive, visionos

I have app which supports two destinations: iPhone and Apple Vision, both using their native SDKs (iOS, visionOS). When I need to wrap iOS-only code inside `#if os(iOS)` compiler directive and I try to build `visionOS` app, the code inside `#if os(iOS)` block is used as well.

[image]

[image]

The only way how I can tell compiler that this code is for `iOS` is by saying it is not for `visionOS`.

[image]

Why is that? Is `visionOS` some kind of sub-platform of `iOS`? I didn't find any documentation for it. I'm using `Xcode 15.0 beta 5` and you can simulate it simply by creating new `visionOS`-only app.

Comment: Probably, similar to `macCatalyst`, I think Apple is trying to make it all work with little adapting.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, it was probably just bug on `Xcode 15.0 beta 5`, on `Xcode 15.0 beta 8` directives work as expected.